Copy table to another table with an extra column at the start
In the past, I have successfully copied tables from one to other like this:
INSERT INTO myhistory SELECT p.*, NOW(), '' FROM mymain p

Here, the extra columns were at the end.  However, I now have a different case where the extra column is (a) at the beginning of the table and (b) it is an auto-incremented column.  So I tried this:
INSERT INTO `starchive` null, SELECT f.* FROM `stflagged` f

This isn't working.  I also tried 0 instead of null, but that fails too. Any ideas?

The NULL is part of the select statement so the number of fields match. So:
INSERT INTO `starchive` SELECT NULL, f.* FROM `stflagged` f

Or explicitly list table columns:
INSERT INTO `starchive` (col2, col3, col4) SELECT f.* FROM `stflagged` f

example ref: https://dbfiddle.uk/5vKYKdwC

Great! That worked!  I thought that was one of the variations I had tried, but obviously not.  Thanx much!
